# Docker SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hey I am trying to compose a docker image and run it up at the same time(if that's how you put it). I am using

Windows 10 Home version, which means I have to use the docker toolbox and the quickstart terminal.

I am trying to run the following command in my directory where my Dockerfile resides:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.build.yml up -d
```

And I get the following error when I run it:

```
ERROR: SSL error: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] sslv3 alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:1864)
```

Anyone has an idea on how to go about it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers